# How to pass session id to Ninject container to get session bound instance of object?

Tags: c#, containers, inversion-of-control, ninject

I am struggling to implement a functionality to enable custom session scope for Ninject IoC. My requirements are that for a unique session id (int) I will get a new instance of object bound to a particular interface. 
Second requirement is that it has to be possible at place where Get is called.

The problem is that IKernel.Get<> has no means to pass a session id. I cannot also use .InScope() because static instance will have no access to a current session id. (No Session.Current pattern can be used).

Session can only be distinguished by a unique integer number and there can be multiple sessions running at the same time.

Any ideas apart from creating a separate container per each session? I am afraid it may be expensive. Copying a container? Is it possible with Ninject?

Thanks, Radek

Comment: Prevent letting the construction of object graph be dependent on runtime data. Read [this](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are wrong.

- `InScope` does not require a static field. The method signature is `InScope(Func<IContext, object> scope)`. So you have access to `IContext` - which is not static.
- [`Get`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/005e6f9e38414a38ae7c6aaf346c74ec64212609/src/Ninject/Syntax/ResolutionExtensions.cs) overloads accept `IParameter`s. These are put on the `IContext`. You can create a custom `IParameter` implementation for your session-scoping. So there is a way to pass your session to `Get`.

However, having just an integer as session id will probably not work. As the scope object needs to be a reference-type, not a value type, there's boxing involved. Ninject might not properly support this - in case it compares references instead of the integers values. Furthermore, clean-up (`IDisposable.Dispose()` calls) might be done prematurely. Ninject keeps a weak-reference to the scope. If the scope object does not implement [`INotifyWhenDisposed`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Infrastructure/Disposal/INotifyWhenDisposed.cs) it periodicall checks whether the weak-reference is dead. When it's dead, it will do resource cleanup. Of course, if ninject gets its own "box" object and only keeps a weak-reference to that, the GC is free to collect this at any time. Meaning your resources could get disposed before the scope actually ends.

So you would need to wrap your scope-id in an object (and keep a reference to this object, not just to the value), and preferrably have it implement `INotifyWhenDisposed` for deterministic resource cleanup, too.

---

Hint: Maybe [`InCallScope`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope/wiki/InCallScope) - contained in `Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope`would be a better fit for your use case.

Another possible alternative is employing a [`ChildKernel`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel) per session. That's similar to creating a kernel per session - but it's not as heavyweight.

Comment: The "static field" was just an acronym/shortcut. But I am more interested in custom IParameter implementation, it sounds interesting. So, in short I can provide extra parameter, a boxed session id. Could you please outline on how would I resolve to a new instance or existing instance based on this? Did you mean something like:

InScope(x => x.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "SessionId"))? 
Actually you would not need to imeplement a new IParameter, just provide it when calling Get. Something like Get<Interface>(new Parameter("SessionId", _currentBoxedSessionId)); Right?

Comment: @RadekStrugalski You don't really need a custom parameter but IMHO it's just a bit cleaner. Up to you. "boxed session id" - no, i would create a class `Session` which has an int field. Then you need to use this class/object in your application to reference the session, not just for the parameter. If you just use it in the parameter, there's no-one keeping a reference to it and you will end up with ... well.. "undefined" behavior.

Comment: @RadekStrugalski unless you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is hard to provide an exemplar implementation to showcase solving your problem.